# give Bootstrap style to RAW .php page

Tags: html, css

Hello to every one im Nick, thanks in advance for your patience im absolute new at this, and thankks for this awesome comunnity.
SO here is the thing, i have a php page that displays info from an mysql query.
It checks a database for records and then displays them in a very simple table view, no css, no bootstrap no nothing/
I've seen a lot of tutorials on how to "beautify" this result table with bootstrap but i cant understand how to do it, where to insert lines, codeees, refs html, im a mess and im desperate.

the php code of the page is this.

---

```
<?php 
include_once 'conexion.php';

session_start();
$per=$_SESSION['id'];
echo $per;

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();

}
$e = "SOLICITUDES ";
$where="where iduser = ".$per." order by id DESC";
$sol=$_POST['xsol'];


if(isset($_POST['buscar']))
{
    if(empty($_POST['xsol']))
    {

    }
    else
    {
      $where="where ca like '%".$sol."%' or exp like '%".$sol."%' and iduser = ".$per." order by id DESC"; 
    }
}

//consulta SQL 
$_datos="SELECT * FROM solicitud $where";
echo $_datos;
$consulta = mysqli_query($con, $_datos);
?>


    <div>
            <DIV><h1> <?php echo $e; ?></h1></DIV>

            <div> <a href='form_note.php'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'> Agregar Nueva Solicitud </button></a> 
            <br><br>
            </div>
             <DIV>
             <label><b>Listado de Solicitudes: </b></label>
             <br>

            <
              <section>
                <form method="post">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar.." name="xsol" />
                  <button name="buscar" type="submit">Buscar</button>
                </form>
              </section>

              <br>
             <div><table border="1"> <!-- iniciamos la tabla -->
             <?php  

              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) { 
                     echo "<tr>";

                          if(!empty($row['exp'])) {echo "<td><label>".$row['exp']."</label></td>";}
                          else {echo "<td><label>Exp</label></td>";}

                          if(!empty($row['ca'])) {echo "<td><label>".$row['ca']."</label></td>";}
                          else {echo "<td><label>Ca</label></td>";}

                          if(!empty($row['firma'])) {echo "<td><img src='firma/thumb/".$row['firma']."'></td>";}
                          else {echo "<td><img src='firma/thumb/check_yes.gif'></td>";}

                          echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Ver </button></td>";

                          echo "<td><a href='solpdf.php?id=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>PDF </button></td>";

                          echo "</tr>";

                }
              ?>
             </table>
             </div>
          </DIV>
 </div>
```

I have this on a site working, but as i said before, i want to give it some style, to the table, the texts to all.
I have tryied alot of ways but it seems i cant get the logic of it. 
I repeat this works, its simple ugly. PLease helpme to give this some bootsrap style.

Thanks in advance 
NickVOID

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Are you asking "How can I use CSS to make my page look better?" or something more specific?

Comment: Tadman tks for your info, really ill check the method you mention

Comment: "Are you asking "How can I use CSS to make my page look better?" or something more specific? " tadman,, YESSS PLEASE !!!! exactly that, if its responsive it would help a lot too

Comment: That's way too broad a subject for the Q&A format of Stack Overflow. You'll need to take an introductory course into CSS, of which there are many, in order to better understand the basics. The absolute minimum takes a few hours to absorb, and learning something like Bootstrap a few days.

Comment: Excellent tadman tks

Comment: If I read the title right, @INITONE is asking how to apply Bootstrap to his page. Bootstrap has great [getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) docs. Check out the starter template.